# Ajax call is not working inside click function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { sorted_ids: sortedId, sorted_row_ids: sortedRowId,
                                  sorted_col_ids: sortedColId},
    url: "/inventory/drag",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
         alert("sucess");
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("unsucessful");
    }

});

<%= button_to "save","#",:title => "save",:id => "save_button" %>
```

When I click the button I am getting alert but ajax call is not getting triggered. Can anyone help me?

Comment: check your browser's net tab to see whether the request is failing

Comment: Also I would recommend moving the script inside a dom ready handler...

Comment: I checked my Browser.No request has been sent.

Comment: Is the alert appearing?

Comment: ya..i am getting alert.

Comment: datatype: 'json',  remove comma at the end. Was this not giving error in your browser firebug

Comment: No I dont see. Also removed the comma results the same.

Comment: Hey guys I corrected the syntax its working like charm.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 data: {sortedText:"sortedText"},
```

instead of

```
 data: "sortedText",
```

and use:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

instead of

```
datatype: 'json',
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ajax call in the following way:-

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "{'name':'xyz'}",
    url: "abc.aspx",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
         alert("sucess");
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("unsucessful");
    }

});
```

Comment: I used ajax call in your way. Its working fine in Chrome and IE. But not working in Firefox.Please see my edited question.

Comment: In firefox use firebug and find exactly what error comes.(Try to reload your page by ctrl +  F5 or ctrl + R). I don't think there is some browser issue in this...

Comment: you are right.I am getting the ajax request in firebug. but its not actually get into my app. Also request in firebug has 0B in size.I am newbie to ajax.

Comment: ajax request is empty.What does mean if its empty?

Comment: is it hit your application, put debugger on server side code.......,and first try with POST instead of GET